# How can I redirect to another page in ajax with data?

Tags: javascript, ajax

I have managed to save a form and returned success. I want to redirect to another page using `window.location.href = '/home';` which is working well. I however want to pass the success message to the home page after redirecting. When I use `window.location.href = '/home'+ data;` the message concatenates with the URL. How do I go about this?

Comment: You can set flash session data in method where form request has been pointed. On /home page blade you can check for existence of that data and express it if it is there. [Docs](https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/session#flash-data).

Comment: If you're using JavaScript only you have basically 3 options: Cookies, local/session storage or passing data as URL parameters in the query string.

Answer (score 1):

Can you share your code to help with your question?

Maybe you can use something like this:

```
return view('YOUR VIEW', compact('data'));
```

If that doesn't work, you could use `LocalStorage`:

```
localStorage.setItem("data", data);
window.location.href = '/home';
```